# sqlite : query additional columns with compound select

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I have a table containing this columns :

```
| name | city | time | version |
```

I use this query to find all rows with new adresses between 2 versions :

```
select name, city from adresses where version = 2 
except 
select name, city from adresses where version = 1
```

It's working but i would like to retrieve also time value but time value change between each version.

I would like something like that :

```
NOT WORKING
select time from adresses where version = 2 and 
(select name, city from adresses where version = 1 
except select name, city from adresses where version = 2);
```

Someone know how i can do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I'm understanding your question correctly, but based on the query you wrote, I think this is what you actually wanted:

```
SELECT time FROM adresses a
INNER JOIN (
   select name, city from adresses where version = 1 
   except 
   select name, city from adresses where version = 2
) new ON new.name = a.name AND new.city = a.city
WHERE version = 2
```

If you are looking for the time difference between two versions of a record (which is what you also mention in your question) then you could do something like this:

```
SELECT a2.*, a2.time - a1.time as time_diff
FROM adresses a1
INNER JOIN adresses a2 ON a1.name = a2.name AND a1.city = a2.city
WHERE a1.version = 1 AND a2.version = 2
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot. It was the first query i wanted :-)